# When dismissing a fullscreen modal the viewWillLayoutSubviews method does not get called

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

I am trying to track down a problem where the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) method do not get called after dismising a controller displayed using -

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and dismissing with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];.
```

This view controller is displayed on top of a `UISplitViewController` as the result of a button being pressed in the detail area. When I rotate the device, without the modal up, I do get the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` callback. However, the problem is, when I rotate during the presentation of the model, it does not update the views correctly and recalculate the view bounds after dismissing it. According to the IOS 5 release notes I should get a `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after dismissing the modal view controller.

For comparison, I created a bare bones app with none of my other code in it and it works as documented, it will call `viewWillLayoutSubviews` after the modal is dismissed.

I have been going over and over my real app code and can't find anything wrong. I am looking for suggestions for things to do help figure this out. Why would the callback work when rotating but not work when the modal is dismissed? Could it be something with my view hierarchy?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the delegate method `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. The WillLayoutSubviews is only called when the view's bounds change (which happens when you rotate the device).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this might be the basis for a work around, I do get the callback viewWillAppear in my real app, however, in my bare bones app I get the viewDidLayoutSubviews callback every time I exit the modal. So I am trying to understand what is different and if it is a symptom of a deeper problem.

Comment: Yes, doing what you suggest is a basis for a work around which is not too bad. so in my viewWillAppear, I call [self.view setNeedsLayout]; This corrects the problems, but according to the documentation and my simple app, I should not need to do this. I gave you an up vote but I want to keep this open. Thanks

Comment: since no other answers have come in I am going to accept your answer.